# Доступ ко члену-типу шаблонного типа извне шаблонного типа

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Скажите, пожалуйста, как Стандарт C++ регламентирует доступ ко вложенному члену-типу шаблонного типа при условии, что вложенный член-тип не зависит от шаблонных параметров объемлющего типа?

Например:

```
template <typename X>
class Type
{
    public:
    class SubType
    {
    };
};

using Alias = typename Type::SubType;// How can I do that?
```

То есть, возможно ли получить доступ к `Type::SubType` извне `Type` без указания параметров шаблона? Если да, то как это сделать? Если нет, то почему?

Comment: А если, например, будет специализация, которая обеспечит зависимость от параметра?... Это достаточная причина? :)

Comment: Вложенный тип шаблона класса всегда зависит от параметров шаблона.

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, кажется, это на кусок ответа смахивает ;)

Comment: Могли бы вы объяснить немного подробнее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Type<X>`  - будет отдельным типом для каждого X. Поэтому, `Type<X>::SubType` - тоже отдельный независимый тип.

Стандарт ника не предоставляет возможности проверить, зависит ли вложенный тип от шаблонного параметра. (Предполагается, что всегда зависит.) Даже если такой зависимости де-факто нет, все равно эти типы имеют разные имена, а `std::is_same` должен возвращать `false`.

```
static_assert( std::is_same_v< Type<int>::SubType, Type<void>::SubType> == false );
```

Можно либо сделать шаблонный алиас:

```
template <typename X>
using Alias = typename Type<X>::SubType;
```

Либо объявить SubType отдельно:

```
class Type_SubType
{
};

template <typename X>
class Type
{
    public:
    using SubType = Type_SubType;
};
static_assert( std::is_same_v< Type<int>::SubType, Type<void>::SubType> == true );
```